# Bash script to loop through values in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

```
host_list=abc@xyz.com,cde@xyz.com,zbe@xyz.com
```

I want to write loop in bash script to scroll through each of this host_list & try to grep a particular string `'abc@xyz.com'`. if its present then return yes or no

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a string variable instead of an array?

Comment: `host_list=( abc@xyz.com cde@xyz.com zbe@xyz.com )` would be more sensible; then you can just `for host in "${host_list[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: In evaluating answers in the linked duplicates, keep [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) in mind. `array=( $string )` is an antipattern -- while commonly used, it introduces bugs.